# Invisible cards in Angular using rawg api

Tags: angular

I am trying to get cards to display on my home page for 20 games. But not a singular card shows up at all. If I remove the data interpolation then a card shows up. I'm trying to get the data from the rawg api.

card html

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let game of games">
    <div class="card text-white bg-dark">
      <img src="{{ game.background_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ game.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

card ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RawgDataService } from 'src/app/services/rawg-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-cards',
  templateUrl: './game-cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-cards.component.css']
})
export class GameCardsComponent implements OnInit {

  public games: any = [];

  constructor(private rawgDataService: RawgDataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rawgDataService.getGames().subscribe( response => {this.games = response.data;})
  }

}
```

app html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-game-cards></app-game-cards>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card bg-dark my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title text-center text-white py-3">{{ title }}</h2>
          <ul class="text-center list-inline py-3">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="users" class="btn btn-info">List Users</a>
                </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="/adduser" class="btn btn-info">Add User</a>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

rawg angular service - I'm the most unsure about this portion of the code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RawgDataService {

  private ENDPOINTS = {
    GAME_LIST_URL: 'https://rawg.io/api/games?page=1&page_size=20&key=6d9368c98b03417d9a0cab226f150dc0'
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getGames(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.ENDPOINTS.GAME_LIST_URL);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rawgDataService.getGames().subscribe( response => {this.games = response.data;})
  }
```

to

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rawgDataService.getGames().subscribe( response => {this.games = response.data.results;})
  }
```

As per  JSON data in the below image, the game data is present in the results tag.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the rawg api endpoint you mentioned, you are setting the wrong value to games.

You are trying to set games with the whole response data, though the game list is in "results" field.